# Stop page unresponsive pop up in SuiteScript client script

Tags: client, suitescript2.0

I have a Client SuiteScript with fieldChanged entry point that sets a field on every line item on a sales order after a value on a field is selected. If there are too many line items the Chrome 'Page Unresponsive' pop up comes up. If you keep clicking wait the process will finish. Is there a way to stop that 'Page Unresponsive' pop up?